# Problema al poner invisible una ImageView en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentando poner dos imágenes invisibles al pulsar un botón, la primera no se modifica pero la segunda si...¿alguna idea de por qué puede ser?. Funciona la imagen selected pero no la de ImageRoulette.
Aquí esta el código para la creación de las ImageView

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rouletteImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_play"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ruleta"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageSelected"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rouletteImage"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="177dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/seleccionadorruleta" />
```

Así es como las instancio:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_juego_ruleta);

    jugadores = (Jugadores) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listaJugadores");

    b_start = findViewById(R.id.btn_play);

    selected = findViewById(R.id.imageSelected);
    imageRoulette = findViewById(R.id.rouletteImage);

    nombreJugador = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreJugadorRuleta);
    nombreJugador.setText(jugadores.cambiarDeJugador());

    this.sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    this.intNumber = this.sharedPreferences.getInt("INT_NUMBER", 6);

    addPreguntas();
}
```

Y esta sería la lógica:

```
private void accionesDespuesDeTirar() {
    imageRoulette.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    selected.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar como los instancias?

Comment: Pon el método completo de accionesDespuesDeTirar() ,en qué momento lo llamas y si usas algún thread para esto

Answer (score 1):

Si en tu código:

```
  imageRoulette.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  selected.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

la segunda vista la esconde pero la primera no, la única razón es que la referencia que tomaste para la primera vista no es la correcta, debes estar seguro de definir el id correctamente que en este caso sería `rouletteImage` :

```
rouletteImage = findViewById(R.id.rouletteImage);
```

al obtener la referencia de la vista debes sin ningún problema mostrar u ocultar la vista.

---

Recuerda que también puedes usar `.setVisibility(View.GONE)` :

Hace la vista invisible, oculta también el espacio que tenía en el layout.

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Have la vista visible.

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Hace la vista invisible, pero no oculta espacio que tenía en el layout.

```
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, no es problema de la referencia ya que si en vez poner el código para hacerla invisible en el método lo pongo en el inicializador de la vista (onCreate) si que funciona.